# PHP - current folder / directory name

Tags: php, printing, path, echo, filenames

how can I get the current folder/directory name in PHP?

I have two pages on my site:

`/about` and `/help`

This is my code (in about and help page):

```
<?php

echo dirname("index.php");

?>
```

I want it to return: 'about' if I am on about page. And return 'help' if I am on help page. But it returns nothing.

If I am on this path:
`http://www.website.com/about/index.php` I want it to just return `about`

Comment: use `dirname(__FILE__);`

Comment: I tried putting: `<?php

$current_folder = dirname(__FILE__);
echo $current_folder;

?>` but it prints out the full path like: `C:\xampp\htdocs\about` - I want it to just print out `about` @Saty

Comment: Solved it! Thanks guys! `basename(__DIR__);` worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getcwd();`

or

`dirname(__FILE__);`

or (PHP5)

`basename(__DIR__)`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Answer (score 0):

echo dirname( **__FILE__** );

Will print your file path

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the directory where the current script resides, use `dirname(__FILE__);`

From your question I understand that you want to get it from the url instead. For that you can process the url (useful if URL Rewriting is done)

```
$full_url  = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url_array = explode("/", $full_url);
if(end($url_array)==='index.php' || end($url_array)==''){    
    $key = array_search('index.php', $url_array);
    if(!$key){
    //if index.php is not present and url ends with a '/'
        $key = count($url_array) - 1;
    }
    $target = (array_key_exists(($key-1), $url_array))?($key-1):$key;    
    $dir_name = $url_array[$target];
}else{
    $dir_name = end($url_array);
}
echo  $dir_name;
```